# Token Unknown, Firebird Computed By

Tags: sql, firebird, dml

I'm getting token unknown QTY when executing the below DML, at a complete loss as to why as QTY is contained earlier in the table definition. The error is occurring on the COMPUTED column.

```
CREATE TABLE LINE_ITEMS(
  LINE_ITEM_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  QTY          NUMERIC(10,4) DEFAULT 0, 
  PRICE        NUMERIC(10,4) DEFAULT 0, 
  AMOUNT       COMPUTED BY QTY * PRICE,     
  CONSTRAINT   PK_LINE_ITEMS PRIMARY KEY(LINE_ITEM_ID)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the expression between parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE LINE_ITEMS
(
  LINE_ITEM_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  QTY          NUMERIC(10,4) DEFAULT 0, 
  PRICE        NUMERIC(10,4) DEFAULT 0, 
  AMOUNT       COMPUTED BY (QTY * PRICE),     
  CONSTRAINT   PK_LINE_ITEMS PRIMARY KEY(LINE_ITEM_ID)
);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had discovered that myself and was going to answer my own question. In the Borrie book there is an example of a computed field concatenating strings that does not have parens but the syntax definition above it does have (expr).

Comment: @user1455270 yep, but the book is just that, a book. You could check the documentation from https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ : IB6 LangRef or re-written form scratch FB2.5 Reference. You also could use GUI IDE like IBExpert or FlameRobin and then view the created table as SQL-script